# Get the bound property's PropertyInfo

Tags: wpf, binding, converters, propertyinfo

What I want to achieve is specify specific values for properties that should only be shown in the Designer, but not at runtime.

---

So in my ViewModels, I want to decorate the properties with a custom attribute

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property, AllowMultiple = false)]
public class DesignTimeValueAttribute : Attribute
{
    public object Value { get; }

    public DesignTimeValueAttribute(object value)
    {
        this.Value = value;
    }
}
```

like e.g. this:

```
private string test;

[DesignTimeValue("Hello World")]
public string Test
{
    get { return this.test; }
    set
    {
        if(this.test != value)
        {
            this.test = value;
            this.RaisePropertyChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

and in the XAML part, I want to bind to that property like this:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <DesignTimeValueConverter x:Key="DesignTimeValueConverter" />
</Window.Resources>

<Grid>
    <TextBox Text="{Binding Test, Converter={StaticResource DesignTimeValueConverter}}" />
</Grid>
```

---

So far so good. The `DesignTimeValueConverter` *should* look like this (Pseudo Code):

```
public class DesignTimeValueConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (DesignerProperties.GetIsInDesignMode(this))
        {
            PropertyInfo propertyInfo = ...; // What can I put here?
            DesignTimeValueAttribute attribute = propertyInfo.GetCustomAttribute<DesignTimeValueAttribute>();

            if(attribute != null)
            {
                return attribute.Value;
            }
        }

        return value;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return value;
    }
}
```

but I don't know if there is a way to fetch the bound properties `PropertyInfo`.

---

**How can I access the actual property in a `IValueConverter`, not only the value and its type?**

What could I possibly pass as the converter parameter, e.g. could I use

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Test, Converter={StaticResource DesignTimeValueConverter}, ConverterParameter=???}" />
```

and if so, what should I pass?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fetch the attribute value from DesignTimeValueAttribute, the value converter must use Reflection as follows:

```
((DisplayAttribute(typeof(className).GetProperty(propertyName).GetCustomAttribute(typeof(DisplayAttribute)))).DesignTimeValue;
```

To use reflection it needs two things:

1. name of the class these properties are in
2. name of the property

You can either add a DependencyProperty for the class name to your value converter or create a MultiValueConverter and pass the name of the class as one of the bindings.

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <local:DesignTimeValueConverter x:Key="myDesignTimeValueConverter" ClassName="MyNamespace.MyClass" />
</UserControl.Resources>
```

Then use the converter on the property and also pass the name of the property as the ConverterParameter:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Test, Converter={StaticResource myDesignTimeValueConverter}, ConverterParameter=Test}" />
```